# Aix: why program mail ignore the mbox setting?

Tags: email, aix, mailx

On AIX, I want the mail program to use /root/.mbox instead of default /root/mbox.
I edit mailrc

vim .mailrc

set MBOX=/root/.mbox

the result is not good

```
mail
Mail [5.2 UCB] [AIX 5.X]  Type ? for help.
"/var/spool/mail/root": 2 messages 2 unread
>U  1 root              Tue Jun 22 01:48  13/349 
 U  2 root              Tue Jun 22 01:49  13/349 
? 1
Message  1:
From root Tue Jun 22 01:48:58 2021
Date: Tue, 22 Jun 2021 01:48:58 +0200
From: root
To: root

hello

? q
Saved 1 message in /root/mbox
Held 1 message in /var/spool/mail/root
```

I have tried different setting like those on mailrc

```
set MBOX=/root/.mbox
set MBOX /root/.mbox
set mbox /root/.mbox
set mbox=/root/.mbox
```

but still save to /root/mbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, instead of use this method, valid on old Unix os like  Sco Unix System V

```
myname@scosysv:/usr/myname$ vi .mailrc
".mailrc" 1 line, 19 characters 
set MBOX=/usr/myname/.mbox


myname@scosysv:/usr/myname$ echo hello|mail myname
myname@scosysv:/usr/myname$ mail
SCO System V Mail (version 3.2)  Type ? for help.
"/usr/spool/mail/myname": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 myname         Tue Jun 22 02:04    8/215  
& 1
Message  1:
From myname Tue Jun 22 02:04:28 2021
From: myname@scosysv.UUCP ()
X-Mailer: SCO System V Mail (version 3.2)
To: myname
Date: Tue, 22 Jun 2021 2:04:28 PDT
Message-ID:  <202106220204.aa00403@scosysv.UUCP>
Status: R

hello
& save
"/usr/myname/.mbox"[New file] 8/215
& Held 0 messages in /usr/spool/mail/myname.
```

On AIX we use this method

```
export MBOX=/root/.mbox

echo hello|mail root
mail
Mail [5.2 UCB] [AIX 5.X]  Type ? for help.
"/var/spool/mail/root": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 root              Tue Jun 22 02:16  12/339 
? 1
Message  1:
From root Tue Jun 22 02:16:25 2021
Date: Tue, 22 Jun 2021 02:16:25 +0200
From: root
To: root

hello

? save
"/root/.mbox" [Appended] 12/339
```

of course the variable can be added on .bashrc file or rc file of your shell.

Comment: FYI, the [man page for `mail`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=m-mail-command) lists MBOX as a supported variable.